# howto create an Outlook.Folder Object from Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, mapi

i have this "simple" Outlook-Object:

```
Outlook.Explorer olExplorer = this.Application.ActiveExplorer();
```

in "ThisAddin_StartUp" i register the *olExplorer.FolderSwitch* event to a function olExplorer_FolderSwitch(). There i must create an Outlook-Folder Object from the current Folder:

```
Outlook.Folder f = olExplorer.CurrentFolder as Outlook.Folder;
```

But: the property "CurrentFolder" is of type MAPIFolder and cant be used as *Outlook.Folder*.
How can i "cast" the CurrentFolder-Property to an Outlook.Folder? - without loosing the event-handler? If i do this simple conversion, the object *f* will not fire the event BeforeItemMove - because *f* is NULL where olExplorer.CurrentFolder is not

Answer (score 1):

I have not found an easy way.
You could find the Outlook.Folder from the folders sessions.

If you compare the EntryID you will get the right folder.

```
Outlook.Folders olFolders = OutlookApp.Session.Folders;

for (int i = 1; i <= olFolders.Count; i++)
{
   if (olFolders[i].EntryID == olExplorer.CurrentFolder.EntryID)
   {
      // folder found assign and use it.
   }
}
```

notice the start at 1 and count equal or less to get all your folders.

Answer (score 1):

There are easy way convert MAPIFolder to Outlook.Folder try explicit cast:

```
Outlook.Explorer olExplorer = this.Application.ActiveExplorer();
Outlook.Folder f = (Outlook.Folder)olExplorer.CurrentFolder;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really *get* the issue, as according to the documentation Explorer.CurrentFolder returns an object of type Outlook.Folder, not MAPIFolder. I personally haven't done any VSTO (nor 2007 specific) development, but are you sure you aren't mixing up different versions of the object model?

Anyway, Outlook.Folder and MAPIFolder share the EntryID and StoreID property. You can use those to lookup the corresponding Outlook.Folder using [NameSpace.GetFolderFromID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219901.aspx). The namespace in question is acquired through Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").

Comment: Explorer.CurrentFolder returns an object of type MAPIFolder.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook.Folder is the same as Outlook.MAPIFolder.